# Where to place this Eloquent query logic in Laravel 9?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-9

Let's say I have a model `Book` with a field `published` that is either true or false and I often need to retrieve books that have been published in the current year. I can create following Eloquent query:

```
Book::where(['published', true], ['publish_date', date('Y')])->get();
```

Where should I place this code? In my controller or my model? And how would I call it?

```
Book->getPublished()
Book::getPublished()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you'd use [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes) for handling this commonly accessed logic. Add the following method to your Book model:

```php
class Book extends Model
{
    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        return $query
            ->where('published', true)
            ->where('publish_date', date('Y));
    }
}
```

You can then use this scope in your code via `Book::published()->get()`.

The benefit of declaring the scope, but not including the `->get()` is that you can chain multiple methods when required. For example:

```php
$books = Book::published()->order_by('publish_date')->limit(25)->get();
```